# Trying to read text file in AsyncTask in android, but i get empty result

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to read a text file from the web in an AsyncTask class in android, then pass the result into a static variable, and then load it to a TextView in another class, but i'm get empty results and can't figure it out why. Obviously i'm messing up with something in my code...

Could anyone review this? Thanks in advance!

```
package com.example.cuccandroid;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class readtextfile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

               URL url = new URL("http://example.com/example.txt");       

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                //get lines
                Kezdoh.descriptiontext=line;
            }
            in.close();


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return null;
    }

     protected void onProgressUpdate() {
        //called when the background task makes any progress
     }

      protected void onPreExecute() {
         //called before doInBackground() is started
     }
     protected void onPostExecute() {
         //called after doInBackground() has finished 
     }
      }
```

My class, where im trying to load

```
package com.example.cuccandroid;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import com.example.cluppandroid.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class Kezdoh extends Fragment{

    TextView description;
    static String descriptiontext;
  @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.kezdoh, container, false);
        //GetDescription();
        description = ((TextView)android.findViewById(R.id.description1));

        new readtextfile().execute("http://example.com/example.txt");
        description.setText(descriptiontext);
        return android;
        }   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remember that AsyncTask is executed in a different thread at a different time.

In your case, description.setText(descriptiontext); is executed first.

A good approach would be preventing to use static reference of descriptiontext.

What you could do in this case is to add a constructor to readtextfile and pass the TextView instance. 
onPostExecute() method would be executed after doInBackground() that read the string content. 
Subsequently, any UI related methods should be accessed in onPostExecute() method.

I have slightly modified your readtextfile class as the following:

```
public class readtextfile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

private TextView textViewToSet;
public readtextfile(TextView descriptionTextView){
    this.textViewToSet = descriptionTextView;
    }

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String result = "";
    try {
           URL url = new URL("http://example.com/example.txt");       

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String line = null;

        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            //get lines
            result+=line;
        }
        in.close();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return result;
}

 protected void onProgressUpdate() {
    //called when the background task makes any progress
 }

  protected void onPreExecute() {
     //called before doInBackground() is started
 }

@Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     this.textViewToSet.setText(result); 
 }
  }
```

What you need to do next is to just call

```
new readtextfile().execute("http://example.com/example.txt");
```

and remove this line from onCreateView method

```
description.setText(descriptiontext);
```

Comment: I have tried to implement the code, but the line "return result;" keep saying the "result" cannot be resolved to a variable. If i declare the "result" variable before the Try statement, i receive empty result. What to do?

Comment: Edited to move the "result" before try statement and return type to String. Try to check the logcat, any error has been thrown by catch clause? have you tried running it in debug mode and put some breakpoints?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your `asynctask` class, please check and set your `TextView` in `onpostExecute()` after `super()` is called. Please check the code below.

```
public class readtextfile extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
            try {

                URL url = new URL(
                        "http://example.com/example.txt");

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        url.openStream()));
                String line = null;
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    // get lines
                    response.append(line);

                }
                in.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return response.toString();
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate() {
            // called when the background task makes any progress
        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();

            Log.d("tag", "Response is " + result.toString());
        //set your Textview here
        description.setText(result.toString());
        }
    }
```

Your Main Class

```
package com.example.cuccandroid;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import com.example.cluppandroid.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class Kezdoh extends Fragment{

    TextView description;
    static String descriptiontext;
  @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.kezdoh, container, false);
        //GetDescription();
        description = ((TextView)android.findViewById(R.id.description1));

        new readtextfile().execute("http://example.com/example.txt");

        return android;
        }   
}
```